# How to secure the key in an offline package

Tags: encryption, key-management, decryption, secrets-management

I have a package to be shared to Bob which contains:

- an encrypted `data.zip`
- `Application`, which will have logic to decrypt the data

*Bob* will run `Application` and it will decrypt the data.zip.

Now for the decryption key. I understand that I can maintain a key store where I can keep the key securely which my Application will access and get the key.

But in my case *Bob* will execute the `Application` offline.

Building the `Application` with the decryption key doesn't make sense as *Bob* can easily take the key or logic to form the key from `Application`.

In this scenario, how can I handle the decryption part? What is the ideal solution and how where should I keep the key?

Comment: I think you need to explain more of the context. Why do you need to encrypt something here in the first place, i.e. what threats should the encryption protect from. Encryption should protect data against an attacker but in your case it looks like that you want to protect the data from the end user who actually needs to access to the decrypted data in order to work with the data. Maybe encryption isn't even the right approach to your unknown problem.

Comment: We have a ton of questions here about "how to handle keys in binaries", which is what you are asking.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to assume that `Application` is some kind of proprietary application with to decrypt multiple `data.zip`s for multiple users, else it wouldn't make a lot of sense.

You could try looking into White-box cryptography:

http://www.whiteboxcrypto.com/

This technology is trying to create something similar to your setup, but they keep running into hackers extracting keys via side-channel attacks.

Another solution is to have Bob buy a license key or something similar for your product. Let it be a leaf key from a PKI such that `Application` can decrypt any `data.zip` with it, but that it can also be validated to check of revocation. This last option might be circumvented by a smart Bob that can debug the `Application` application and skip the check.

Comment: Whiteboxcrypto is really a theoretical sollution at the moment. The question is really the problem of DRM that industry tries to solve for years.